# How to do parallel "either-side" short-circuiting with "and" and "or"

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, short-circuiting

Does haskell have a parallel "and" method

```
parAnd :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

such that

```
(a `parAnd` b)
```

will spark the evaluation of a and b in parallel and return false as soon as either a or b evaluates to false (and not wait for the other one)?

Is there some way to implement such a thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally, this is not possible. You can do something like

```
a `par` b `pseq` (a && b)
```

but if `b` evaluates to `False`, `a` is still fully evaluated.

However, this is possible with the unambiguous choice operator created by [Conal Elliott](http://conal.net/blog/) for his Functional Reactive Programming (FRP) implementation. It's available on Hackage as [unamb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb) package and does exactly what you want. In particular, it contains

```
-- | Turn a binary commutative operation into one that tries both orders in
-- parallel. Useful when there are special cases that don't require
-- evaluating both arguments.
-- ...
parCommute :: (a -> a -> b) -> a -> a -> b
```

and also directly defines `pand`,`por` and other similar commutative functions, such that

```
pand undefined False   -> False
pand False undefined   -> False
```

Comment: According to the documentation, amb evaluates its arguments "in separate threads".  Does that mean it actually takes the time to create threads (and all the associated overhead) rather than using the spark pool?

Comment: Oh never mind, I get it.  If the tasks are small enough to care about the overhead of using threads, then there's no reason to use unamb in the first place.

Comment: It's useful even for tasks that are fast "on one side" due to its strictness properties.

Answer (score 6):

This is provided by Conal Elliott's [unamb package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unamb-0.2.5/docs/Data-Unamb.html#v:pand). It uses `unsafePerformIO` under the covers to evaluate both `a && b` and `b && a` on separate threads, and returns when either produces a result.